# Dropdown client-side validation in IE7, using Html.ValidateFor() helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side

I have a weird issue regarding validation of dropdowns on my form.  One drop down is a list of states and is decorated with RequiredAttribute:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="State is required.")]
```

Inside the view, the dropdown and its validation are defined as:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(BusinessLayer.UsStates.GetList())) %>
<% Html.ValidateFor(m => m.State); %>
```

`UsStates.GetList()` returns a `List<string>`.
All my client-side validation (including dropdowns) works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome and even IE8.  However, in IE7 it's broken - even when a state (and its value obviously) is properly selected in the dropdown, validation fails and says "State is required."

**Solved my problem:**

IE7 wasn't happy about the fact that the value attribute of each option wasn't rendered.  So passing a List into the SelectList() didn't cut it.  You have to pass in a list of key/value pair-type objects and pass in the DataValueField and DataTextField parameters, like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(BusinessLayer.UsStates.GetList(), "Value", "Text"))%>
```

That was quite annoying..  :)

Comment: Any javascript errors in IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem:

IE7 wasn't happy about the fact that the value attribute of each option wasn't rendered. So passing a `List<string>` into the `SelectList()` didn't cut it. You have to pass in a list of key/value pair-type objects and pass in the DataValueField and DataTextField parameters, like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(BusinessLayer.UsStates.GetList(), "Value", "Text"))%>
```

That was quite annoying.. :)